# cannot update repositories in ubuntu /

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I wanted to install some software on Ubuntu, but first I wanted to update packages, and I received this :

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                       
Ign:3 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan InRelease             
Err:5 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.209.189.249 80]
Err:6 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.209.189.249 80]
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phpmyadmin/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease                            
Err:9 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.209.189.249 80]
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

I don't know exactly what's happening , since I never had problems before. Can you please help me make this work ? I have Ubuntu 19 version :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

19.10 is EOL since July 2020. See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for all releases and their end dates.
You should get yourself a LTS version - which will be supported for a longer period of time.
Ubuntu 20.04 will be supported until 2025, its EOL even later